# Dot (nested) notation in Angular's interpolate system

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have an object such as:

```
obj = {foo: 42, bar: 'moo'}
```

And an interpolate string such as:

```
s = 'Do {{ bar }} {{ foo }} times.'
```

Interpolating this in Angular:

```
var interp = $interpolate(s);
var res = interp(obj);
console.log(res);  // <--- This will return 'Do moo 42 times.'
```

Is there a way I can express dotted/nested notation? Example:

```
obj = {n: {foo: 42}, bar: 'moo'}
s = 'Do {{ bar }} {{ n.foo }} times.'  // <--- This doesn't work

var interp = $interpolate(s);
var res = interp(obj);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Your code work fine in `jsfiddle`. Try it https://jsfiddle.net/utnqdfwd/

Comment: @DmitriyLoskutov Indeed, I got confused with my own code. Anyways, is there a way I could evaluate an already evaluaten interpolation? https://jsfiddle.net/utnqdfwd/2/

Comment: I mean, look at the fiddle I pasted. `x` is `n.foo`, but how can I reference the object itself so interpolating `{{ x }}` will actually return the value of `obj.n.foo`?

Comment: I guess https://jsfiddle.net/utnqdfwd/3/. But I think it is not good :) Try to read more about it from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Answer (score 2):

[$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service can solve your problem.

> $parse service converts angular expression into a function.

You should convert expression *n.foo* to a function :

```
var parserFunc = $parse(obj.x)
```

Now, if you use parserFunc function with a parameter that you want to parse, it returns the value according to expression. Solution can be like:

```
var module = angular.module('name', []);

module.directive('app', ['$interpolate','$parse', function ($interpolate,$parse) {
    return {
    link: function () {
      var obj = {n: {foo: 42}, bar: 'moo', x: 'n.foo'};
      obj.parserFunc = $parse(obj.x);

      var s = 'Do {{ bar }} {{ parserFunc(this) }} times.';  // <--- x is 'n.foo'

      var interp = $interpolate(s);
      var res = interp(obj);
      console.log(res);
    }
  }
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document, ['name']);
```

Code work fine in [jsfiddle.net/utnqdfwd/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/utnqdfwd/5/)